# EBean preserve sort order from in clause

Tags: java, ebean

I have a Database with documents which I index with Lucene - not all of the fields a relevant for search, so just a subset of them is actually indexed. A search gives me a list of document ids ordered by their score. I use this list to find Ebeans

```
PagingList<MyDoc> pagingList = Ebean.find(MyDoc.class)
        .where().in("id", idList)
        .findPagingList(pageSize);
```

I would like to preserve the sort order obviously. As far as I know, there's no build in way in EBean, to preserve the order and I couldn't find a sort function, which let's me implement a Comparator either.

Is there any way of doing this?

**update**

As said by Rob, I'm using a List<> and sort it myself.

```
PagingList<MyDoc> pagingList = Metadata.find(MyDoc.class)
    .where().in("id", idList).findPagingList(PAGE_SIZE);
Page<MyDoc> pg = pagingList.getPage(page);
List<MyDoc> results = pg.getList();

Collections.sort(results, new Comparator<MyDoc>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyDoc o1, MyDoc o2) {
        if (idList.indexOf(o1.id) > idList.indexOf(o2.id)) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (idList.indexOf(o1.id) < idList.indexOf(o2.id)) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Which DB engine do you use ?

Comment: H2 at the moment but will be a postgres in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use findList() and not findPagingList() - that will return a List... and then on the list sort it yourself using your own comparator.

Comment: Ok. Note that you should use findList() with setMaxRows() and setFirstRow() and not findPagingList().  findPagingList() is going to be deprecated in v4.0.1.